# How to watch window scope variable from angular controller properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am aware that I can wrap out of scope variable in functions to somewhat achieve this

```
$scope.$watch(
function () {
    return $window.mArray 
}, function(){
    // code
}
);
```

But this doesn't get triggered unless something else triggers the digest cycle, is there a more proper way to do this ?

Comment: demo http://dojo.telerik.com/oFife/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oFife) of how you should use

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $window){
$scope.data = 0;
$scope.changeData = function(){    
  $scope.data = Math.random();
}
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue, oldValue){
console.log(newValue);
}, true);

});
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: you are watching angular controller scope variable not window scope . .